# Random.choice gives the same answer

Tags: python, bots

I'm new and wanted to make a reddit bot with random.choice but if I write the same phrase twice in the same comment it gives the same answer

```
phrase = 'summon_bot'

import random
  char1 = ["character1", "character2", "character3"]

  if phrase in comment.body
     reply = comment.body.replace(phrase,str(random.choice(char1)))
```

and when a comment is for example :"summon_bot and summon_bot are the best characters" it gives the same answer for both phrases

Comment: It just replace both occurences of `phrase` with randomly chosen `char1` item.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't throw an indentation error? Or a syntax error from the missing colon?

Answer (score 2):

I think, that's what you're trying to do.

```
import random

phrase = "summon_bot"
char1 = ["character1", "character2", "character3"]

reply = comment.body
while phrase in reply:
    reply = reply.replace(phrase, str(random.choice(char1)), 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

read your code as:

```py
phrase = 'summon_bot'

import random
  char1 = ["character1", "character2", "character3"]

  if phrase in comment.body:
     random_choice = random.choice(char1)
     #random_choice is now a stored variable. Fixed, is the same each time you use it
     reply = comment.body.replace(phrase,str(random_choice)) #replaces all occurences of phrase with fixed random_choice
```

You need a way to evaluate `random.choice(char1)` for each occurence. 
E.g.:

```
reply = comment.body
while phrase in reply:
     random_choice = random.choice(char1)
     reply.replace(phrase, random_choice, 1) #extra argument to only replace first occurence
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the documentation of *replace()*, it replaces all occurrences it finds, not just the first one.

Comment: Downvoted and flagged as not an answer. This should be a comment.